# React - Fetch multiple apis

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, get, fetch-api

I want to make a get request to multiple apis at the same time from 2 different urls, and then I want to just update the array "items" in the state with the new property "img", not to overwrite it. I want to keep and properties in the first request.
Here is my try.

```
   componentDidMount(){

      let url = ``;
      let url2 = ``

        fetch(url,{
          method: 'GET'
        })
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          const newItems = responseJson.items.map(i => {
            return{
              itemId: i.itemId,
              name: i.name,
            };
          })
          const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
            items: newItems
          });

          console.log(newState);
          this.setState(newState);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
        fetch(url2,{
          method: 'GET'
        })
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          const newImg = responseJson.item.map( data=> {
            return{
              img: data.picture.url
            };
          })
          const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
            items: newImg
          });

          console.log(newState);
          this.setState(newState);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can call two seperate APIs. The problem that you are having is that the API call that is returning last is overwriting the data that was saved from the first API call. Here is the code that will fix this.

```
componentDidMount(){

  let api1 = `https://myapiexample1.com`;
  let api2 = `https://myapiexample2.com`;

  let promise1 = fetch(api1)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => json.items.map(item => {
    return {
      itemId: item.itemId
      name: item.name
    }
  }))

  let promise2 = fetch(api2)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => json.items.map(item => {
    return {
      img: item.img
    }
  }))

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then(results => results[0].concat(results[1]))
  .then(items => this.setState({itmes}))
}
```

An alternative approach which is not as clean, but is similar to what you are currently doing is to make sure to include the old state when adding new items to the state:

```
this.setState({
  items: newItems.concat(this.state.items)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I tried your solution but can you please check my updated question? it's so frustrating!

Comment: I'm still a little confused, are you trying to create an `items` object that looks like this: `{{itemId: 123, name: test1}, {img: ...}}` or like this: `{{itemId: 123, name: test1, img: ...}}`

Comment: Like the last one {{itemId: 123, name: test1, img: ...}}

Comment: Your answer seems to be right but it gives me this error, i don't know why "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" for the map in "promise2". I don't know if I can use 2 map functions in the same function.

Comment: That would indicate that there is no `items` property in the JSON that is returned from the api. Are you sure that is the format? Try console.log(json) and see what the output is...

Answer (score 1):

Use Promise.all():

```js
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all, it will resolve when all promises are ok or reject if any fails.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all